# Assistance with CodeIgniter login script

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get an error with this line:

```
$result = $this->user->login($username, $password);
```

Placing call to a method or object that is undefined.

Controller:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit(' No direct script access allowed');

class verifyLogin extends CI_Controller{

    function _contruct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('User','',TRUE);

    }

    function index()
    {
        //validate the credentials
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //if validation fails then redirect to login page
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
            else
            {
                //go to private area
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }
    }

    function check_database($password)
    {

        //validate against database 
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        //query the database
        $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

        if($result)
        {
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $sess_array = array(
                'id' => $row->id, 
                'username' => $row->username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
                return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
                return false;
                }
            }
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Model
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this-> db -> select('id, username, password');
        $this-> db -> from('users');
        $this-> db -> where('username = ' . "'" . $username . "'");
        $this-> db -> where('password = ' . "'" . MD5($password) . "'");
        $this-> db -> limit(1);

        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: should it be `$this->User->login`, do you need to  instantiate the model??

Comment: Replace `$this->load->model('User','',TRUE);` with this `$this->load->model('User');`. Model loader function second parameter in the valiable name which you assign it. Eg if second param is `test`, then the model would be accessible via `$this->test`

Comment: i notice that the example; class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {... also calls the constructor.

Comment: the exact error is undefined property:verifyLogin::$user

Comment: I am running xampp could it have something to do with settings in php.ini? Or the config for CI?

Comment: @Kristian: Take a look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html.  `$this->load->model('User','',TRUE);` Tells it to auto-connect to the DB.

Comment: Have you implemented Kristian's suggestions? If not your should. If you have, update your code so that we can continue to debug it.

Comment: Okey. Then try load User model from check_database function. If that works then problem is in your constructor. Or you can put die() in to your constructor to check if it is called.

Comment: And if doesn't work, then problem is with loading model. Eg filename in not capitalized, loader class bug, etc. Just in case you could check if your model file name has capitalized first letter :)

Answer (score 4):

Constructor function name is misspelled in your code "_contruct" instead of __construct
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#constructors

Comment: Ok I moved the load user model to check database function but now it gives me invalid username or password when the info is in the database.